# IE11 audio tags not working after various ad hoc workarounds

Tags: javascript, html, audio, internet-explorer-11, html5-audio

This question has been asked and solved various times, but the fixes I've found on SO haven't been working for me so now it is my turn to ask.

My audio tags work just fine in chrome and Edge, but not IE11.

In the advanced media settings I have play web audio enabled, I have this in my head tag although probably not necessary:
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`
I have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top with no comments above or whitespace.
My audio tags are created as such:

`$("body").append($("<audio id='<%=aCodeElement.getDescription()%>'> <source src='<%=aCodeElement.getCode()%>' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>"));`

And in the browser they look like:

```
<audio id="RingTone01"> 
    <source src="http://10.37.0.102/console/sounds/ringtones/Ring-Tone-01.wav" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

They are triggered as follows:

```
for(var i = 0; i < soundlist.length; i++)
        {
            if (soundlist[i] == tone)
            {

                 document.getElementById(soundlist[i]).play();
                 
                
            }
        }
```

I've ran the debugger to ensure that IE11 can find the right element, but it does not play the audio. Typing in something like

```
var audioelem = document.getElementById("RingTone01");
audioelem.play();
```

Console just says undefined and no audio plays. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

And one last thing, html5test.com says my internet explorer has no Web Audio API, whereas chrome does, so perhaps this might point to something.

Comment: Please state the exact error message you're getting. Also the mime type for *.wav is `audio/wav`

Comment: There's no error message whatsoever, just no audio playback. I'll update the mime type, and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: Didn't seem to do the trick unfortunately.

Comment: I'm also seeing that the play() function returns a promise, but I've read that promises aren't supported by IE11?

Comment: Using an mp3 and `type="audio/mpeg"` did the trick for me, plays fine in IE11. I recommend adding the `controls` attribute to your `<audio>` while debugging this; it said "Invalid Source" when I tried a wav file.

Comment: ah you're right. IE11 doesn't support wav audio files. Why must they make everything so difficult!

Comment: From your last comment, it seems that you have solved the issue. You could also check the support information [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=wav). I suggest you to put the solution as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE11 doesn't support wav files, so I created a test mp3 file and the audio tag worked.